# OpenCV: Flann matcher crashes

Tags: opencv

I am trying to run an application that detects features in an image, but when I run the code for `BRISK` features, `BRIEF` descriptors and `FlannBased` matcher, it crashes and saying:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=0
) in buildIndex_, file /home/stefan/git_repos/opencv/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line 315
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/stefan/git_repos/opencv/modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp:315: error: (-210) type=0
 in function buildIndex_

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried to clean and restart your computer? source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860875/opencv-error-when-using-miniflann

Comment: Yes, but no changes, the same error, does it need 64 descriptor values for flann? Or the type should be int, float or double for flann? I have some fixed values (32 and CV_8U) that I want to fix now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably you have tried to use KD-Tree or KMeans? They works only for CV_32F descriptors like SIFT or SURF. 
For binary descriptors like BRIEF\ORB\FREAK you have to use either LSH or Hierarchical clustering index. Or simple bruteforce search. 
You can manage it automatically, for example like this.

```
cv::flann::Index GenFLANNIndex(cv::Mat keys)
{
  switch (keys.type())
    {
    case CV_32F:
      {
        return  cv::flann::Index(keys,cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4));
        break;
       }
    case CV_8U:
      {
        return cv::flann::Index(keys,cv::flann::HierarchicalClusteringIndexParams(),dist_type);
        break;
      }
    default:
      {
        return cv::flann::Index(keys,cv::flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4));
        break;
      }
    }

}
...
cv::flann::Index tree = GenFLANNIndex(descriptors);
```

Comment: I have no special lines, I do it the same for all the descriptors, features types, is SIFT and SURF descriptors, features on KD-Tree. Is the default for the two different from the others?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the type is CV_32F I shall fix that

Comment: Because of different nature of the binary descriptors, you have to use different matching method for them, the problem is not just CV_32F.

Comment: Ouch... That is bad! Do you know a link for learning more? I have not done this kind of stuff before

Comment: I have added an example how you can handle it.

Comment: And if I want to use different matches also, to have some comparisons (like `BruteForce` and `Flann`)? Shall I split it, too?

Comment: You can just add some parameter to function and generate Index based on switch of this parameter instead of raw type.