# LSH slower than BruteForce matching

Tags: c++, performance, opencv, image-processing

I need to do similarity matching between two images. For that, I'm using ORB keypoints detector and ORB descriptor extractor from OpenCV in C++

My problem is in the matching. I decided to test two types of matching: ***FLANNBasedMatcher*** using LSH and ***BFMatcher***. Where, according to documentation and both algorithms, LSH suppose to be faster than brute force (the first one doesn't compare all descriptors one by one and the second one does).

When I tried both, I got BFMatcher faster than LSH (But much faster), and I have no idea why and how to fix it.

At the beginning I though it needed more keypoints in order to see a difference, and I decided to increase this by letting ORB detect up to 70000 keypoints:

```
OrbFeatureDetector detector(70000);
```

But this made it even slower.

I don't know if my assumption of LSH being faster than brute force is wrong, or if I'm doing something wrong with my code.

My code:

```
//Detector
    int numKeyPoints = 70000; 
    OrbFeatureDetector detector(numKeyPoints); 
    detector.detect( image, keypoints); 

// Extractor
    OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    extractor.compute(image, keypoints, descriptors); 

// BFMatcher
    BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING); 
    matcher.radiusMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches, 30);


// LSHMatcher
    FlannBasedMatcher matcher(new flann::LshIndexParams(6,12,2));
    matcher.knnMatch(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches, 1);
```

The average time:

- Brute Force = 0.006 s per image
- LSH = 0.04 s per image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it known bug. 
Try to use Hierarchical Clustering - it is much faster than bruteforce.

```
cv::flann::Index tree(Desriptors,cv::flann::HierarchicalClusteringIndexParams(),FLANN_DIST_HAMMIN‌​G); 
cv::Mat indices, dists; 
tree.knnSearch(Desriptors2, indices, dists, 1, cv::flann::SearchParams());
```

Comment: Is there any bug report about this?

Comment: Well, not "bug" as bug for bug report - see http://answers.opencv.org/question/924/lsh-matching-very-slow/

Comment: Yes I read that post, but It's a different problem. They match one descriptor with a trained vector of descriptors, I'm just matching two different descriptors, and even changing the parameters, is not getting faster. Anyway, can you refer me to documentation or examples of Hierarchical Clustering? I did some research but didn't find something helpful.

Comment: If you talk about usage, you just generate other index http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634730/opencv-flann-matcher-crashes/23639463?noredirect=1#comment36322682_23639463 
If about how it works - it is in the paper "Fast Matching of Binary Features" http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/12mujaCRV.pdf

Comment: Thank you, just one question, does the hierarchical clustering supports hamming distance? and if it does, how can I specify it? (like for the euclidean is cv::flann::FLANN_DIST_EUCLIDEAN)

Comment: It supports only hamming distance, as far as I remember, so it is default distance.

Comment: I got an "Unsupported format or combination of formats" error. I'm using binary descriptors (I checked and the Mat was CV_8U type). Maybe there's something extra I should do?

Comment: There can be two reasons. First - I`m using OpenCV 2.4.9. Which one do you use, may be it haven`t it implemented yet?

Second, I don`t use FlannBasedMatcher, I do it manually like 
 cv::flann::Index tree(Desriptors,cv::flann::HierarchicalClusteringIndexParams(),FLANN_DIST_HAMMING);
  cv::Mat indices, dists;

  tree.knnSearch(Desriptors2, indices, dists, 1, cv::flann::SearchParams());
;

Comment: I was using 2.4.8, and now it's compiling. One last question, after the knnSearch, I got two Mat objects (indices and dists), what do they mean? and how could I use them to compare?, for example using findHomography function.

Comment: I`m sorry, but have you ever look at documentation?
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html

indices – Vector that will contain the indices of the K-nearest neighbors found. It must have at least knn size.
dists – Vector that will contain the distances to the K-nearest neighbors found. It must have at least knn size.

Comment: Yes I did, but I needed a more detailed explanation. Thanks

Comment: You check if distance is less than 64 - according to ORB - than the match is good. Match = i-th point from Descriptors2 to indices[i] from Descriptors